# Why do the clouds look blocky?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, volumetrics

I imported vdb clouds into Blender and noticed in the viewport they looked very blocky. So I rendered it out and it looks like this. I tried changing the light path and volume settings but nothing seemed to work. Maybe I'm missing something but it's very annoying. Help!

Specs:

- Blender 2.93.0 LTS (128 samples, rendered on cpu (gpu looks the same just takes longer))
- 16 thread ryzen 9 4800hs
- rtx 2060 super max-q mobile
- 1tb ssd
- 16 gb ram

[image]

Comment: can you share that vdb file or your whole file?